# How to get the correct permissions for SpreadsheetApp.openById

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google sheets file where I have created a bound script. The script does a quick web query, pulls and parses some data, and then updates the sheet with the new data.

I can run it with the sheets file open easily enough, and everything works as planned. I want to switch it over to running on a daily timer. To make sure I'm working with the correct sheet, I changed:

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
```

to

```
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MyProjectID');
```

Unfortunately, when I run the script now, I get the following:

```
You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required 
permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets (line 6, file 
"macros")
```

My understanding is that openById requires certain permissions. How can I authorize the script to get those permissions? At this time, I'm just running this personally, so it doesn't need to be deployed to the world at large.

Comment: You probably have `//@OnlyCurrentDoc` in your code, as this enables a reduced permission requirement for your script (`.../auth/spreadsheets.currentonly`). Remove that comment line and the automatic scope detection will prompt you with the new authorization screen when you next run it. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354071/error-when-using-spreadsheetapp-and-formapp-in-the-same-standalone-script

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when using SpreadsheetApp and FormApp in the same standalone script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52354071/error-when-using-spreadsheetapp-and-formapp-in-the-same-standalone-script)

Comment: @tehhowch Perfect--that was the issue. It's working for me now. I'll confirm that it runs tomorrow morning as well, but that appears to have been the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Note that a bound script works just dandy using `SpreadsheetApp.getActive()` even for time-based triggers.